# Google map doesn't fill the <div>

Tags: google-maps

I have a problem: on one of the pages of my site I use a google map and the problem is that it doesn't fill at 100% the div - the map fills at about 20% of the div. I tried couple of things but I can't fix this. I will be grateful for any help in resolving this issue! You may see the problem at: http://travulum.com (please click "menu", than "travel videos" and click one of travel videos - the first time google map fills the div at 100%, but if you click on second travel video - the second time google map doesn't fill the div at 100% and etc.....
I use this script:

```
function updatePlayer(video_data){



    $('#map_canvas').empty().removeAttr('style');



    var BigPlayer = $('#bambuserPlayer').empty();



    if(typeof video_data !== 'undefined'){



        var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(video_data.lat), parseFloat(video_data.lon));


        var myOptions =  {       

            zoom:10,

            center: map_center,

            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,

            streetViewControl: false,

            panControl: false

        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

            position: map_center,

            map: map,

            icon: createMarkerIcon('archived')

        });


        var url = 'http://embed.bambuser.com/broadcast/' + video_data.id;

        BigPlayer.html('<iframe width="450" height="450" src="'+ url +'" frameborder="0" ></iframe>');

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have hidden the map div, you need to call `map.checkResize()` to tell the API that you changed the size of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a size for the map in some CSS. I checked in FireBug and indeed the map takes up the entire space of the otherwise empty div with id="map_canvas"

```
 #map_canvas { height: 400px; width: 600px; }
```